# ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred while creating a Google Cloud Storage bucket

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, deployment, gcloud

I was following this tutorial : [link](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine)

This is the google cloud version i used :

```
(venv) C:\Users\user\Desktop\python-docs-samples\appengine\standard_python3\django>gcloud --version
Google Cloud SDK 367.0.0
bq 2.0.72
core 2021.12.10
gsutil 5.5
```

During the deploy process I was getting the following error:

```
(venv) C:\Users\user\Desktop\python-docs-samples\appengine\standard_python3\django>gcloud app deploy
Initializing App Engine resources...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred while creating a Google Cloud Storage bucket.
```

I've searched from various sources and they suggest running this:

```
gcloud config set app/use_deprecated_preparation True
```

But when I run the error appears:

```
(venv) C:\Users\user\Desktop\python-docs-samples\appengine\standard_python3\django>gcloud config set app/use_deprecated_preparation True
ERROR: (gcloud.config.set) Section [app] has no property [use_deprecated_preparation].
```

I running it in the project directory folder.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: To isolate the potential issue, could you attempt to perform this deployment from, ideally, the Cloud Shell? Otherwise, a different computer with a different environment could suffice

Comment: Have you been able to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Does you network have a proxy?
Maybe you can try the command without a proxy.

Comment: As per tutorial, I use cloud_sql_proxy.exe. I've tried turning it off and running gcloud app deploy again but still the same error appears